# How to show the label in the address templates in billing and shipping address in the Magento

Tags: magento

How to show the label in the address templates in billing and shipping address in the Magento.

The Magento show the billing and shipping Addres by default as:

```
dummy name
test@domian.com
Steet address
Delhi, Delhi, 19403
India
T: (976) 676-5674
```

I like to be displayed as:

```
Name: dummy name
Email Adress: test@domian.com
Address: Steet address
State: Delhi, 
City: Delhi, 
Pin Code: 19403
Country: Inda
Telephone: (976) 676-5674
```

Can anybody help my in this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @

> Admin -> System -> config -> Customer Config -> Address Templates